Running the Windows 11 development VM images under KVM
Microsoft offers sample development VMs for Windows 11 for download (here).
Has anyone had success getting these to boot under KVM?  I've used qemu-img to convert the image to a raw disk image and written the image to an unused logical volume and set up a VM using virt-manager but it blue-screens immediately (about a second) on boot.
Does anyone know a way to get these images to boot?  Or am I stuck reinstalling from an ISO?

If you prefer an ISO install, virt-manager will pick up the necessary tpm files if you install the swtpm package. W11 24h2 install just fine.

For anyone who comes after me, changing:
<cpu mode="host-passthrough" check="on" migratable="on"/>

to
<cpu mode="host-model" check="on"/>

fixed this immediate problem for me.
